# How to install PyAuto on Win7 64bit Python2.7?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, automation

The page here http://www.chromium.org/developers/testing/pyauto#TOC-Running-PyAuto-using-prebuilt-binaries suggests using the files here http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?path=Win/140227/ to install it yourself, but I'm not exactly sure what I have to do.

I ran mini_installer successfully, put pyauto and _pyauto in the site_packages, and the dll in system32 folder.

This is the error I get when I try to run the automated_ui_test.exe http://pastebin.com/Ab0vCCWk

I am also unable to figure out where this is supposed to be `chrome/test/pyautolib/fetch_prebuilt_pyauto.py` EDIT: found it here http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/test/pyautolib/

EDIT2: Got it 'built' or something, now I have a set of files in the path I set. Now when I try to import pyautolib, I get the following error: `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I think this has something to do with me being on 64bit. Generally when this happens, I check out http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ which has quite a few 64bit python packages, but it's not there this time.

**What need to do to run PyAuto on a Windows 7, 64bit machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for pyAuto on 64-bit Chrome currently http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support

> A 64-bit version of Chromium can be built on Linux by using the -Dtarget_arch=x64 flag on the GYP build system.  (This is the default on 64-bit Linux systems.)
>
> The 64-bit version of  the V8 JavaScript engine used by Chromium can be built separately using the --arch=x64 flag in v8's Scons build system. This works on both the Linux and Mac OS X platforms.
>
> Neither Chromium nor V8 has a 64-bit version on the Windows platform right now. However, Chrome does run on 64-bit Windows as a 32-bit application. V8 should only need a small number of changes to build on the Windows platform.